# cannot find a module 'ng2-typeahead'

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to import a `Typeahead` component and getting 
`cannot find a module 'ng2-typeahead'` error.

I have ASP.NET Core application, downloaded this on from here : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnetcore-angular2

and using tutorial from here for `Typeahead`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-typeahead

What I did:

1. Added in package.json:

`"ng2-typeahead": "1.0.0",`

2. Added code in `system.congfig.js`:

   `paths: {
           // paths serve as alias
           'npm:': 'node_modules/'
       },
     var map = {
        ....

       'ng2-typeahead': 'npm:ng2-typeahead',
     }; 
     var packages = {

       'ng2-typeahead': { main: 'ng2-typeahead.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
     };`
3. Getting error by importing `Typeahead` in `app.module.ts` file:

`import { Typeahead } from 'ng2-typeahead';`

Am i doing something wrong or missing something ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you added Typeahead in app.module.ts like this - `declarations: [ Typeahead ],` ?

Comment: Yes, still getting this error that `cant't find a 'ng2-typeahead' module`.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` after adding it to your package.json?

Comment: Yes tried that, also deleted node_modules and tried to rerun `npm install` did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this workaround-

First, Copy ng2-typeahead.ts into your app folder.

In app.module.ts, import from ng2-Typeahead like this-

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { Typeahead } from './ng2-Typeahead';
//import { Typeahead } from 'ng2-Typeahead';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, Typeahead  ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Use Typeahead in your component like this-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<h1>My First Angular App</h1>
      <typeahead
  [(ngModel)]="selectedFruit"
  [list]="fruits"
  [searchProperty]="'searchText'" [displayProperty]="'name'"
  [maxSuggestions]="2"
  (suggestionSelected)="fruitSelected($event)"
  placeholder="Begin typing a fruit">
</typeahead>
      `
    })
    export class AppComponent { 

        fruits: any[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "1 - Apple",
      searchText: "apple"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "2 - Orange",
      searchText: "orange"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "3 - Banana",
      searchText: "banana"
    }
  ];

  selectedFruit: any = this.fruits[0];

  public fruitSelected(fruit) {
    this.selectedFruit = fruit;
  }
}
```

Output result:

[image: output result]

See if this helps.

Comment: Yeah it works, thank You, but still I have no clue why it does not work with an example which i have provided... Will try to find a solution without a workaround ;)

Comment: If you find proper solution then please do share on this post. otherwise, you can raise issue here - https://github.com/brinkmanjg/ng2-typeahead/issues

Comment: How to use remote data with this?

Comment: @Jitendra Just fetch it using http.get and assign it to [list] of typeahead