# ng2-typeahead and browserify: Unexpected value 'Typeahead' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular

I've beat my head on this for days now. I've attempted this solution, which doesn't exactly apply: [cannot find a module 'ng2-typeahead'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678385/cannot-find-a-module-ng2-typeahead). This is my first project, so I might be doing something silly.

I'm trying to browserify an app that uses Typeahead. When I run it without that everything is fine, but unfortunately my app's pretty big and I need to pare it down a lot. When I do, I get an error and the app doesn't work. I've been over the examples on the typeahead documentation page a thousand times, and copied and pasted from it to avoid typos, but it's not working. Below is my error, and below that my smallish app.module.ts and system.config.js

13:22:43.808 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'Typeahead' declared by the module 'AppModule'
    [16]https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:18801:33
    [16]https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:18788:19
    [16]https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:21478:26
    [16]compileModuleAndComponents@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:21416:34
    [16]https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:21407:18
    [17]bootstrapModuleWithZone@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:29098:20
    [17]https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:29080:20
    [9]<@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:1561:1
    s@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:1:639
    e@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:1:818
    @https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/app/bundle.js:1:404
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:232:17
    Zone.prototype.run@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:114:24
    scheduleResolveOrReject/<@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:502:52
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:21
    Zone.prototype.runTask@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:28
    drainMicroTaskQueue@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:401:25
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@https://pluto.probono.net/scripts/related-content/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:339:25

APP.MODULE.TS:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { ScheduleModule } from 'primeng/components/schedule/schedule';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EllipsisPipe } from './ellipsis.pipe';
import { ContentDisplayComponent } from './content-display.component';
import { ContentItemService } from './content-item.service';
import { Typeahead } from 'ng2-typeahead';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

enableProdMode();

@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, ScheduleModule, FormsModule ],
providers: [ CookieService ],//, ActivatedRoute
declarations: [ AppComponent, ContentDisplayComponent, EllipsisPipe, 
    Typeahead ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

SYSTEMJS.CONFIG.JS

```
(function (global) {
if(window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
basePath = "";
} else {
basePath = "/scripts/related-content/";
}
System.config({
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': basePath + 'node_modules/',
  '': basePath
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',
  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
  'moment': 'npm:moment',
  'primeng': 'npm:primeng',
  'ng2-typeahead': 'npm:ng2-typeahead',
  'angular2-cookie': 'npm:angular2-cookie' 
},

packages: {
  app: {
    main: './bundle',/*main.min*/
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'moment': { 
    main: 'moment.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'primeng': { 
    main: "primeng",
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-cookie': { 
    main: "./core",
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'ng2-typeahead': { 
    main: 'ng2-typeahead.js', 
    defaultExtension: 'js' 
  }
  // 'ng2-typeahead': { 
  //   main: './index', 
  //   defaultExtension: 'js' 
  // }
}
});
})(this);
```

Comment: Try like this- `import { Typeahead } from 'ng2-typeahead/src/ng2-typeahead';`

Comment: Thanks. Trying that, I found that I received the same error message as before.

Comment: Can you try to use `ng2-typeahead` with quickstart example from official site? This will help you to identify exact issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm on a deadline and don't really have time to pursue this to such an extent. I found (but with a couple of gotchas) that I could implement the PrimeNG autocomplete in a short amount of time, and was able to browserify that without a hitch.